# ffmpeg make slideshow with images and videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow with ffmpeg that should contain videos and images. Since as far as I know, ffmpeg cannot do this in one step (which would be of course the preferable step)
I'm breaking it up to make a slideshow of some images and concatenate the resulting video with another video.

The problem with this is that when making a slideshow with ffmpeg (like described here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) the framerate is adjusted to make it possible to view one image for a longer time.

Now I've got multiple videos with different framerates to concatenate which is no good (I didn't got it working).

I also tried to make the slideshow with a higher framerate (with `-vf fps=25`) but I didn't got this working.

(since I have images from different locations/not all images of the current directory should be concatenated at once I really need to use the concat demuxer (as far as I know))

Does someone know how to do this right?

---

What I already tried:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i tmp -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf fps=25  output.mkv
```

with a file tmp looking like this: (see the link above for reference)

```
file /path/to/file1.JPG
duration 2
file /path/to/file2.JPG
duration 2
file /path/to/file2.JPG
```

This gives me a video which somehow only the first image.

---

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i tmp -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

with a file tmp looking like this: (see the link above for reference)

```
file /path/to/file1.JPG
duration 2
file /path/to/file2.JPG
duration 2
file /path/to/file2.JPG
```

This gives me a file which shows all images at the right rate (everything right up to now) but I'm unable to concatenate it with the right video (25fps) with `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i <(printf "file ${PWD}/%s\n" "output.mkv" "video.mp4") -c copy out.mkv`

---

EDIT: The main problem is the concatenation of these two Files:

```
$ mediainfo video2.MTS
General
ID                                       : 1 (0x1)
Complete name                            : video2.MTS
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 8.95 MiB
Duration                                 : 8 s 240 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 9 024 kb/s
FileExtension_Invalid                    : ts m2t m2s m4t m4s tmf ts tp     trp ty

Video
ID                                       : 256 (0x100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 8 s 320 ms
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 159 r2991 1771b55
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00

Audio
ID                                       : 257 (0x101)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low         Complexity
Format version                           : Version 4
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Codec ID                                 : 15-2
Duration                                 : 8 s 192 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -21 ms

Menu
ID                                       : 4096 (0x1000)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Duration                                 : 8 s 240 ms
List                                     : 256 (0x100) (AVC) / 257         (0x101) (AAC)
Service name                             : Service01
Service provider                         : FFmpeg
Service type                             : digital television
```

and

```
$ mediainfo output.mkv
General
Unique ID                                :     28406040384100140874396026026809692875 (0x155ECDEBB2C5FEFE07B31D86D8B512CB)
Complete name                            : output.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 10.2 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 83 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 14.0 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100
Writing library                          : Lavf58.29.100
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L6
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 6 s 63 ms
Width                                    : 5 184 pixels
Height                                   : 3 888 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 159 r2991 1771b55
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 /     deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 /     psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low         Complexity
Codec ID                                 : A_AAC-2
Duration                                 : 6 s 83 ms
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Writing library                          : Lavc58.54.100 aac
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Comment: Added additional information

Comment: All inputs must have the same attributes. `video2.MTS` and `output.mkv` have different width, height, sample rate. Are both of these videos created by you from the images? How many images are there? Are you also trying to concat random videos?

Comment: Since I was used to the demuxer which can handle some differences in the input files, I wasn't used to look at this aspect. Thanks for explaining. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Need you to answer the questions in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh, yes I was concatenating quite different things (was used to it from the demuxer) but I've got it now with either creating a filterchain or preprocessing the files. The amount of images in the slideshow varies (now for my script) and I tried to concatenate videos made from images (slideshows), and normal videos.